# Postfix is unable to send email to gmail

Tags: server, postfix, gmail

I've installed Postfix on my local server (Ubuntu 16.04 ran through Virtualbox) and 
it seems impossible to send an email to gmail. It works with other mailboxes but not gmail.

Here's my simple PHP script:

```php
$headers ='From: "nom"<dev05@web.fr>'."\n";
$headers .='Reply-To: dev05@web.fr'."\n";
$headers .='Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1"'."\n";
$headers .='Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit';

$address = 'me.myself@gmail.com';

$test_mail = mail($address, 'My subject', 'My message', $headers);

if($test_mail == true)
{
  echo 'Email sent';
}
else
{
  echo 'Cannot send the email';
}
```

I've noticed error messages in the `/var/mail/web` file:

```
Final-Recipient: rfc822; me.myself@gmail.com
Original-Recipient: rfc822;me.myself@gmail.com
Action: failed
Status: 5.7.1
Remote-MTA: dns; gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 550-5.7.1 [2a01:e35:2430:e090:a00:27ff:fe23:1da]
Our system has detected that 550-5.7.1 this message does not meet IPv6 sending guidelines regarding PTR 550-5.7.1 records and authentication. Please review 550-5.7.1 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=IPv6AuthError for more information
550 5.7.1 . ay9si74475139wjc.120 - gsmtp
```

so I modified the following line in the `main.cf` file:

```
inet_protocols = ipv4
```

Now there is no longer error messages in the `/var/mail/web` file but 
I still don't receive the emails in my gmail box.

Answer (score 2):

Did you review https://support.google.com/mail/?p=IPv6AuthError like the SMTP response suggested?

**TL;DR:** GMail expects certain entries in the e-mail header and the DNS record that verify the legitimacy of the sender to avoid spam. This applies to both IPv4 and IPv6 senders though the specific expectations may vary.

How to put these entries in place is too broad and largely unrelated to Ubuntu and therefore off topic on AskUbuntu. Please refer to our sister site [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com) for such questions.